# Epson Stylus Color Photo R200 won't print

Tags: printing

I have a Mac Mini (late 2012) with Mavericks installed. It is connected via USB to an Epson Stylus Color Photo R200 inkjet printer.

When I print, the print job window says

```
Stopped - Unsupported colorspace = -1, 2 pages
```

I have run Software Update.  This is the first time I have tried to use the printer, normally it connects to my old PC and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

A [new print driver for this printer](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/support/supDetail.jsp?oid=29081&infoType=Downloads) was made available for Mavericks in September of '13. Have you downloaded and tried this new driver? I had to update the driver for a Epson Stylus Color Photo R300 for a client of mine to make it work on Mavericks.

Comment: Yep I tried this.  The page just tells you to run Software Update and when I do, it says no updates are available.